# Left Join Column Filter by Month then cross join to a master table

Tags: mysql

Hi I am a beginner in my sql I will really appreciate any advice

I have main table

```
  Address       Val1         Mat 
     tbla        10          Mat1  
     tbla         2          Mat2       
     tbla        23          Mat3    
     tbla         5          Mat4
```

this rows need to be shown in each month like this

```
              Output
Address     Val1      Mat           MonthCreated
 tbla        10       Mat1             January
 tbla         2       Mat2             January
 tbla        23       Mat3             January
 tbla         5       Mat4             January

 tbla        10       Mat1              February
 tbla         2       Mat2             February
 tbla        23       Mat3             February
 tbla         5       Mat4             February
```

up until december but i need to join the income from other table
my query is like this

```
  SELECT dttry.*, all_months.*
        FROM (SELECT
           t1.Address,t1.mat,
           COUNT( DISTINCT t1.id ) AS `Val1`,t1.mat as 'Mat'
          , COALESCE(i.Income , 0 ) AS `Income`
        FROM tbladds1 t1
        JOIN tbladds1_type tt ON tt.id = t1.t_type_id
        JOIN tbladdress m ON m.id = t1.t_mid
        JOIN tbladdressfr mf ON mf.id = t1.t_floor_id
        JOIN tblppl mp ON mp.t_mid = m.id
            AND mp.t_type = 'try'
            AND mp.t_system_id = 'ok'
        left join (
                SELECT
                     CAST( SUM(r.t_payment_total) AS decimal(18, 2) ) AS `Income`
                FROM reserv r
                INNER JOIN newtbladds1 t ON t.t_parent_id = r.id
                WHERE r.t_status != 'Pending'
                AND r.t_status != 'Booked'
                AND r.c_mid = m.id  AND  (t.c_start_date) BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/01/31'
                GROUP BY
                    t.t_type_id
            ) as i on t1.t_type_id = i.t_type_id 
->this is income for january



     left join (
                SELECT
                     CAST( SUM(r.t_payment_total) AS decimal(18, 2) ) AS `Income`
                FROM reserv r
                INNER JOIN newtbladds1 t ON t.t_parent_id = r.id
                WHERE r.t_status != 'Pending'
                AND r.t_status != 'Booked'
                AND r.c_mid = m.id  AND  (t.c_start_date) BETWEEN '2018/02/01' AND '2018/02/31'
                GROUP BY
                    t.t_type_id
            ) as ifebruary on t1.t_type_id = i.t_type_id 

->this is income for february 


        GROUP BY
            t1.t_tool_type_id) as dttry

    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 'January' AS MonthCreated UNION ALL
     SELECT 'February' UNION ALL 
     SELECT 'March' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'April' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'May' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'June' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'July' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'August' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'September' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'October' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'November' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'December') AS all_months 


 Output
    Address     Val1    Mat       Income       MonthCreated
     tbla        10     Mat1         0            January
     tbla         2     Mat2         30           January
     tbla        23     Mat3         10           January
     tbla         5     Mat4          0           January

     tbla        10     Mat1          0            February
     tbla         2     Mat2         30           February
     tbla        23     Mat3         10           February
     tbla         5     Mat4         0            February
```

but for the income column of february it should be not the same as january
 it should be

```
income
1
2
7
8

 Desired Output



    Output
    Address     Val1           Income       MonthCreated
     tbla        10              0            January
     tbla         2              30           January
     tbla        23              10           January
     tbla         5               0           January

     tbla        10              1           February
     tbla         2              2           February
     tbla        23              7           February
     tbla         5              8           February
```

Comment: That's a beast of a query can you simplify it whilst still illustrating your problem?

Comment: Pretty impressive query for a complete beginner...

Comment: thank you for responding to my question my problem is I think in my left join because I need t.c_start_date based on each month in my cross join. I am really a beginner and doing research  and asking question to be able to make this query I really appreciate any advice also I didnt put the ifebruary.Income in my select query

Comment: I'm having a problem getting my head around the address always being tablea in your main table is that really the case?

Comment: yes I am sorry and really appreciate it its always tbla for the address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to give a full answer unless you can provide sample data from all your tables but you almost certainly do not need a sub query for every income month and I would make life simpler by unioning month numbers rather than names and then label afterward. For example

```
drop table if exists maintable;
create table maintable(
Address varchar(10),      Val1 int,        Mat varchar(10));
insert into maintable values
(     'tbla'    ,    10    ,      'Mat1'),  
(     'tbla'    ,     2    ,      'Mat2'),     
(     'tbla'    ,    23    ,      'Mat3'),    
(     'tbla'    ,     5    ,      'Mat4');

drop table if exists income;
create table income(id int auto_increment primary key, mat varchar(10),dt date,amount int);

insert into income (mat,dt,amount) values
('mat2','2018-01-01',10),('mat2','2018-01-01',20),('mat3','2018-01-01',10),
('mat1','2018-02-01',1),('mat2','2018-02-01',7),('mat3','2018-02-01',8),('mat4','2018-02-01',9),
('mat3','2018-10-01',10);


select s.address,s.mat,s.val1,
        coalesce(i.income,0) income, 
        case    when s.monthcreated = 1 then 'jan'
                when s.monthcreated = 2 then 'feb'
                when s.monthcreated = 3 then 'mar'
                when s.monthcreated = 4 then 'apr'
                when s.monthcreated = 5 then 'may'
                when s.monthcreated = 6 then 'jun'
                when s.monthcreated = 7 then 'jul'
                when s.monthcreated = 8 then 'aug'
                when s.monthcreated = 9 then 'sep'
                when s.monthcreated = 10 then 'oct'
                when s.monthcreated = 11 then 'nov'
                when s.monthcreated = 1 then 'dec'
        end as mmm

from
(
select all_months.* , maintable.*
from
(SELECT 1 AS MonthCreated UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 3 UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 UNION ALL
     SELECT 6 UNION ALL
     SELECT 7 UNION ALL
     SELECT 8 UNION ALL
     SELECT 9 UNION ALL
     SELECT 10 UNION ALL
     SELECT 11 UNION ALL
     SELECT 12) AS all_months 
cross join maintable
) s
left join
(
select mat mati,month(dt) mm ,sum(Amount) income
from income
where dt between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
group by mat,month(dt)
) i
on i.mati = s.mat and i.mm = s.monthcreated
order by s.monthcreated,s.mat;
```

Where the income sub query works out which month the income is for per mat.

Result

```
+---------+------+------+--------+------+
| Address | Mat  | Val1 | income | mmm  |
+---------+------+------+--------+------+
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | jan  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |     30 | jan  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |     10 | jan  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | jan  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      1 | feb  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      7 | feb  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      8 | feb  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      9 | feb  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | mar  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | mar  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | mar  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | mar  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | apr  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | apr  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | apr  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | apr  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | may  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | may  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | may  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | may  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | jun  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | jun  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | jun  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | jun  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | jul  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | jul  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | jul  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | jul  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | aug  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | aug  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | aug  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | aug  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | sep  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | sep  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | sep  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | sep  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | oct  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | oct  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |     10 | oct  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | oct  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | nov  |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | nov  |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | nov  |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | nov  |
| tbla    | Mat1 |   10 |      0 | NULL |
| tbla    | Mat2 |    2 |      0 | NULL |
| tbla    | Mat3 |   23 |      0 | NULL |
| tbla    | Mat4 |    5 |      0 | NULL |
+---------+------+------+--------+------+
48 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are really great it worked thank you thank you very much. I  really appreciate it